# What's the correct markup to use a figure element with an img and a figcaption as a link?

Tags: html

So far i've used the following (just a rough outline):

```
<figure>
    <a>
       <img>
       <figcaption></figcaption>
    </a>
</figure>
```

On validation i've got now the following error:

> Element figcaption not allowed as child of element a in this context.

Per definition figure has to be the direct ancestor of figcaption so it interferes with my a tag. What would be the correct and most elegant way to make the whole figure element still be marked up as a link. Best regards Ralf

Comment: Yeah you are right. I am sorry, i was searching beforehand but haven't found it. :( Thanks for the link and pointing me to the solution!

Answer (score 0):

This seems elegant:

```
<a>
  <figure>
    <img>
    <figcaption></figcaption>
  </figure>
</a>
```

That way figcaption is a child of figure, and the whole figure is a link.